# onSaveInstanceState is not getting called

Tags: android, start-activity, activity-state

I have an activity which starts various activities for result codes and on getting results in `onActivityResult` method it starts appropriate activity based on result code.

`onSaveInstanceState` is not getting called in Activity which started for result.

For example Navigation Activity starts Activity A as :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQUEST_CODE);
```

Then A finishes by setting result code so App will redirect to Navigation activity again and `onActivityResult` method will called.

So my question is: Why Activity A's `onSaveInstanceState` is not getting called at finish and navigation back to Navigation Activity  ?

Comment: Have you added configChanges for Activity A  in your manifest?

Comment: no I have not added any config changes for that activity and just declared that activity

Comment: @RahulGupta what changes shoud I made in mnifest for Activity A

Comment: onSave will not be called on natural app finish scenario. It is called on orientation change and if os kills your app. Whatever you are doing in onSaveInstance you can do it in onDestroy too.

Comment: @RahulGupta How I can Store activity state  in onDestroy

Comment: When you have called finish(), then why do you want to save the activities state ? onSaveInstanceState is generally used for orientationchanges

Answer (score 7, accepted):

onSaveInstanceState() is only called if the Activity is being killed.

I don't know what exactly you want to do in that method, but you probably should move your code to the corresponding methods of the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html :

> Note that it is important to save persistent data in onPause() instead of onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) because the latter is not part of the lifecycle callbacks, so will not be called in every situation as described in its documentation.

Also the [method description for onSaveInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) describes exactly your situation:

> Do not confuse this method with activity lifecycle callbacks such as onPause(), which is always called when an activity is being placed in the background or on its way to destruction, or onStop() which is called before destruction. One example of when onPause() and onStop() is called and not this method is when a user navigates back from activity B to activity A: there is no need to call onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) on B because that particular instance will never be restored, so the system avoids calling it. An example when onPause() is called and not onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) is when activity B is launched in front of activity A: the system may avoid calling onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) on activity A if it isn't killed during the lifetime of B since the state of the user interface of A will stay intact.

Comment: T  I have written code to save Parcelable array list of Parcelable Objects and it is not permanent data. I just want previously  modified list when I User come back on that activity. Actually on other activity I have A button for Add More which redirects again to this activity

Answer (score 1):

The method `onSaveInstanceState()` isn't called when an `Activity` finishes naturally like on a back button press. That's your app itself destroying the `Activity`. The method is only called if the Android OS anticipates that it may have to kill your activity to reclaim resources.

If the `Activity` then actually gets killed by Android, the OS will make sure you receive a call to `onRestoreInstanceState()` as well passing the same bundle you used to save your activity's state in `onSaveInstanceState()` method.

From the docs:

> This method is **called before an activity may be killed** so that
>   when it comes back some time in the future it can restore its state.
>   For example, if activity B is launched in front of activity A, and at
>   some point activity A is **killed to reclaim resources**, activity A will
>   have a chance to save the current state of its user interface via this
>   method so that when the user returns to activity A, the state of the
>   user interface can be restored via `onCreate(Bundle)` or
>   `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)`.

Comment: I have written code to save Parcelable array list of Parcelable Objects and it is not permanent data. I just want previously modified list when I User come back on that activity. Actually on other activity I have A button for Add More which redirects again to this activity

Comment: If the data is not permanent i.e. you can't save it to a file or shared prefs etc. then the calling activity (the one with the add button) should hold onto this list and pass it as `Intent` extras when starting the view list activity. This activity should be started with `startActivityForResult()` so that it can pass the modified list back to the calling activity.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue happening to me on a "drawer menu" part of a "main activity", because I had overridden the "onSaveInstanceState" method in my main activity but had forgotten the call to super.onSaveInstanceState() (which, as a result, would never call the "onSaveInstanceState()" method of my "drawer menu" which was part of this main activity).

In other words: make sure you don't forget your calls to "super.onSaveInstanceState()" where necessary.